# An equality with factorials

Tags: combinatorics

Prove that
$$2\times 2! + 3\times 3!+4\times 4! +....+n\times n!=(n+1)!-2$$
I know that it can be proved by mathematical induction, but I want to prove it without using the mathematical induction.
I tied the equation $$C^n_0 + C^n_1 + C^n_2 +...+C^n_n=2^n$$
But I did not get any thing useful.

Comment: Hint: Telescoping sum.

Comment: Are you sure that you have the supposed identity correct?  On the left side you have several positive terms being added to $n\times n!$, which is strictly greater than $n!$ which is strictly greater than $(n-1)!$ which is greater still than $(n-1)!-2$...

Comment: RHS should be $(n\color{red}{+}1)!-2$ instead.

Comment: I am sorry it is as you said that is a misstyping @JMoravitz

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Hint: 
$$\sum_{k=2}^n k\cdot k!=\sum_{k=2}^n (k+1-1)\cdot k!=\sum_{k=2}^n (k+1)!-\sum_{k=2}^n k!$$

Answer (score 15):

$2\times2!=3!-2!$

$3\times3!=4!-3!$

...

$n\times n!=(n+1)!-n!$

Add them all up then $3!,4!,...n!$ cancel out.

Therefore LHS$=(n+1)!-2$

Comment: thank you so much  @abc

Comment: You are welcome:)

Comment: does it work for any natural number or for $ n \geq 2$ only @abc

Comment: @HussienMohamed the factorial function is only defined for non-negative integers.

Comment: i know that , my questions is , does this sum works for any non-negative integer or for any integer $\geq 2$ Only ?

Comment: Do you think it works for n=1 or not?

Comment: The sum starts with $2\times2!$

Comment: And it indeed works for $n\ge2$

Comment: Thank you @ abc